# Monitoring for more than 20 BLE beacon regions using CLLocationmanager in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon

Currently I am using CLLocationmanager to monitor for BLE beacon regions in iOS.

I know I can range beacons if i want more than 20 regions but unfortunately ranging would not allow me to register entry(RegionDidEnter) and exit(RegionDidExit) events as far as I know.

In my use case I need to trigger actions on user's entry and user's exit in a particular beacon region even when app is in killed state or in background.

I need a efficient way to do this as if I look for significant location changes it also uses battery and also using beacons would not make much sense then if i use GPS.

Comment: Specifically why does your use case require more than 20 regions?  Could you combine your regions so you only have 20?

Comment: @davidgyoung  Let's just say one shop or venue may have more than one beacon and each of these shops/venue need to be identified uniquely. For eg. user enters one shop, app right now is in killed state, we need to push notification like welcome to XYZ shop, and on exit also we trigger an action(we get name of shop by sending uuid to server and getting details). Combining regions would not allow me to do this. I was interested if we can range beacons inside monitoring code when a regionDidEnter event occurs to get uuid in background

Answer (score 3):

When `didEnter` happens, iOS will launch your app into the background and give it a few seconds of execution time to handle the event. You can use that time to start ranging, receive the ranging results, and since ranging always provides full UUID/major/minor info, trigger an appropriate action based on that.

Pseudo-code:

```
let myUUID = x
startMonitoring(myUUID)

func onDidEnter {
    startRanging(myUUID)
}

func onDidRange(beacons) {
    if beacons.empty { return } // keep ranging until we find something

    let major = beacons.first.major
    if major == 1 { show("Welcome to X") }
    if major == 2 { show("Welcome to Y") }

    stopRanging(myUUID)
}
```

To ensure that your app doesn't get put back to sleep before it manages to range a beacon, you can also use a [background task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623031-beginbackgroundtaskwithexpiratio), then the (pseudo-)code would look something like:

```
func onDidEnter {
    self.task = beginBackgroundTask(expirationHadler: {
        // our background time is up, iOS requires us to finish our work
        stopRanging(myUUID)
        endBackgroundTask(self.task)
    })
    startRanging(myUUID)
}

func onDidRange(beacons) {
    if beacons.empty { return }

    let major = beacons.first.major
    if major == 1 { show("Welcome to X") }
    if major == 2 { show("Welcome to Y") }

    stopRanging(myUUID)
    endBackgroundTask(self.task)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I agree this is the right approach.  For this to work the only limitation is that you may only have a maximum of 20 ProximityUUIDs being monitored.  So you must have regions defined to be UUID only, with null wildcards for major and minor.  And if all stores use one of these 20 UUIDs this will all work.

Comment: Wouldn't that restrict things? I cannot identify each shop distinctly and send notifications when app is killed if I monitor for only 20 shops, Could we have some other workaround here? @davidgyoung

Comment: I personally would use only a single UUID for all beacons, and identify the shops by the major number in the ranging callback.The actual restriction here is that the "enter" event will only trigger once per store, so instead you might not be able to identify different beacons/areas inside the store. But that could also be worked around: when you enter the store, switch the monitoring setup to "in-store" mode and monitor for up to 19-20 individual beacons.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a workaround to this. Register only those regions near to the user location. When the location changes, you can remove regions that are now farther way and add regions coming up on the user’s path.

To save battery when dealing with location, register for significant-change location updates or make use of defer location updates or use visit monitoring.

**Why Core Location limited to 20**

> Regions are a shared system resource, and the total number of regions
>   available systemwide is limited. For this reason, Core Location limits
>   to 20 the number of regions that may be simultaneously monitored by a
>   single app. To work around this limit,

Comment: This would mean user needs to turn on location services every time right? also If it keeps on sending significant location changes over a period of a day won't it use up lot of battery or in turn wouldn't that destroy the use case of beacons if i have to take location anyways?

Comment: Location services is required to be on for beacon detection, anyway.  And significant location changes is designed to work off of cell tower changes so it is very battery efficient unlike GPS.

Comment: @DivyeShah: Reading this document will give you an exact idea about the power saving. Just use the better one that suit your needs. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/LocationBestPractices.html